# A summation formula for number of ways $n$ identical objects can be put in $m$ identical bins

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, integer-partitions, balls-in-bins

A famous counting problem is to calculate the number of ways $n$ identical objects can be put into $m$ identical bins. I know that this problem is somewhat equivalent to [Partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)). There is no closed formula to compute this number, but I found the following formula somewhere (my source is not in english):
$$\sum_{j=1}^{\min(m,n)}\sum_{i=1}^j\frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{j!}C_{i}^{j}i^n $$
And here is the explanation from the source:

We first suppose that bins are not identical. Then we do the counting for when only one bin is not empty, then when only two bins are not empty and so on. In each case, we have to divide the resulting number to the number of permutations of the non-empty bins. In the end, we take a summation over all such numbers.

But I don't get the formula. Where does the $(-1)^{i+j}$ part come from? Why it has to be a double summation?

Comment: Check the case $m = 2$ and you will see that this is certainly not counting integer partitions.  It might be counting some kind of set partition.

Comment: (In fact this is counting set partitions into $m$ or fewer parts, i.e., it is counting the ways to place $n$ *distinguishable* objects into $m$ identical bins, not requiring every bin to be filled.  Compare the second displayed formula in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind .)

Comment: My bad. You are totally right. Thanks. @JBL

Comment: You're welcome!